# Do snRNAs exit the nucleus or not?

Tags: molecular-biology, cell-biology, rna, nucleic-acids

In **Molecular Biology of The Cell** (Alberts, et al., 2015), it lists the various RNAs that are trafficked through the Nuclear Pore Complex (NPC) into the cytoplasm.

The list includes snRNAs, but I have seen it stated elsewhere that snRNAs don't leave the nucleus, that they are made there and perform their function there.

Is MBOC's version correct and snRNAs leave the nucleus, or are the other sources correct and the snRNAs are made, remain, and function in the nucleus?

Answer (score 1):

After transcription of some UsnRNAs, the RNAs leave nuclei first. After assembly of various proteins and modification on the RNAs in cytosol, the RNAs come back to nuclei. In addition, it has been shown that mature U6snRNP shuttles between nuclear and cytosolic fractions in yeasts, if I remember correctly.

http://openi.nlm.nih.gov/detailedresult.php?img=2582628_gkn658f1&req=4